# rails application on production not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

i have a rails application on production which is running using mongrel, I can successfully start the mogrel for the application but when i try to access the application on the URL it is not responding... it is just hanging.

This is the mongrel log... but when I hit xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3001 it is not showing the website but on developent is working fine.

** Starting Mongrel listening at 0.0.0.0:3001

** Initiating groups for "name.co.za":"name.co.za".

** Changing group to "name.co.za".

** Changing user to "name.co.za".

** Starting Rails with production environment...

** Rails loaded.

** Loading any Rails specific GemPlugins

** Signals ready.  TERM => stop.  USR2 => restart.  INT => stop (no restart).

** Rails signals registered.  HUP => reload (without restart).  It might not work well.

** Mongrel 1.1.5 available at 0.0.0.0:3001

** Writing PID file to /home/name.co.za/shared/log/mongrel.pid

Answer (score 0):

may be port 3001 already bind by other process?

Other solution: try to add -a xxx.xxx.xxx.xx to bind mongrel to ip-address.

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas:

- 3001 is not a standard port to have open on your machine - Many OSs, I know, blocks this by default from external access. You may want to find an external machine and see if you can telnet in, or if there's something on your local machine that blocks the port for external access.
- Some low end routers have trouble taking internal connections, looking up the IP pointing at the router and turning them around for access back inside. See if you can access your machine on a private IP address known to your router (192.168.x.x or whatever).

What OS?